# Is it possible to drag a webkit marquee back and forth?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a ticker-tape run but sometimes the text can be extremely long. I've modified the original webkit code to allow the user to pause the ticker when the user mouses over it, but what I'd like is for the user to be able to drag the ticker text back and forth.

I'm not very adept at jQuery, so is there a way using JavaScript/CSS?

```css
.marquee {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  background: GhostWhite;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   {transform: translate(0, 0)}
  100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0)}
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee"><span>Just some dummy text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a library, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a built in drag function that you can use.

You can download a customised version [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

```js
$("#drag-me").draggable({
  axis: "x"
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  background: GhostWhite;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
  cursor: default;
}

.marquee span:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* Make it move */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p class="marquee"><span id="drag-me">Just some dummy text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I am Addting @-webkit-keyframes  safari and chrome browser compatible   /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */ 

   .marquee {
      width: 800px;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #F00;
      background: GhostWhite;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .marquee span {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 100%;
      animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
    }

    .marquee span:hover {
      -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }




   /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes marquee {
      0%   {transform: translate(0, 0)}
      100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0)}
    }


    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
     @-webkit-keyframes marquee {
      0%   {transform: translate(0, 0)}
      100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0)}
    }


    <p class="marquee"><span>css marquee code with webkit browser compatible</span></p>
```